# How to add label for input field using before and after jquery?

Tags: jquery, insertafter

I want to add a label before and after the input field. I need this result.

```
`<label class="containertitle">
<input id="button" type="checkbox" name="AllSalesArea"  >
<span class="checkmarktitle"></span>
</label>`
```

but I received an output like this.

```
<label class="containertitle"></label>
<input id="button" type="checkbox" name="AllSalesArea">
<span class="checkmarktitle"></span>
```

---

This is my code. I need the label close tag at the end of the span.

```
<input id="button" type="checkbox" name="AllSalesArea"  >


$('input[name="AllSalesArea"]').before('<label class="containertitle'>)
$('input[name="AllSalesArea"]').after('<span class="checkmarktitle"></span></label>')
```

Comment: It is not possible with before and after. The input needs to be enclosed into the label and the span can be inserted with the jQuery after command. For the enclosing you need something different.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer:  `.wrap` the input with the label, then add the span with .after (the input) or .append (to the label)

Comment: Thanks freedomn-m.  .wrap has solved my problem.

Comment: Think about accepting one of the answers and if these did not satisfy you please stay in the loop and indicate what you are still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @freedomn-m.

```
$('input[name="AllSalesArea"]' ).wrap( '<label class="containertitle"></label>' );
$('input[name="AllSalesArea"]').after('<span class="checkmarktitle"></span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like so:

```
<input id="button" type="checkbox" name="AllSalesArea"  >

$(document).append('<label class="containertitle'>).append($('input[name="AllSalesArea"]'))
$('input[name="AllSalesArea"]').after('<span class="checkmarktitle"></span></label>')
```

So you append a new element (`<label class="containertitle'>`) to the document (or a more specific element in your layout I expect) and to this label you append the already existing input element (`$('input[name="AllSalesArea"]')`). Then after the input element you add the `<span class="checkmarktitle">`

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a class to both input and span and use [.wrapAll()](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

   > Description: Wrap an HTML structure around all elements in the set of matched elements.

```js
$(".wrap").wrapAll("<label class=containertitle'></label>")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="button" type="checkbox" name="AllSalesArea"  class="wrap">
<span class="checkmarktitle wrap"></span>
```

Comment: Hi guradio, from my end I have only input values. So wrapall is not suitable in this case. But thanks for sharing.